# Are containers available between stages in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is a container that is used in the build stage accessible in the next stage? I have yaml like this:

```
build_backend:
  image: web-app
  services:
    - mysql:5.7
  stage: build
  script:
    - make build

test_frontend:
  image: node:8
  stage: test
  script:
    - make run-tests
```

My tests, that are triggered in `make run-tests` need to run HTTP requests against the backend container if possible?

I was trying to avoid building a new container and then pushing to a registry only to pull it down again, but maybe there is no other way? If I did this, would my web-app container still have access to the mysql container if I added it as a service in the test_frontend job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, containers are not available between stages. Job artifacts (i.e. files) will be passed between stages by default and [can also be passed explicitly betweeen jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies).

If you need to run tests against a container, you should indeed pull it down again from a registry. Then, you can use the *docker in docker* (`dind`) service to run your tests.

I think [this blog post](https://blog.lwolf.org/post/how-to-build-and-test-docker-images-in-gitlab-ci/) explains a similar use case nicely. The testing job that's is described there is the following:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run -d --env-file=.postgres-env postgres:9.5
    - docker run --env-file=.environment --link=postgres:db $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE nosetests --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-package=${CI_PROJECT_NAME} --cover-html
```